# how to iterate for loop using object oriented php

Tags: php

How to iterate for loop using oop

```
$myobj = new number_ series_ class(10);
$myobj->print_number();
```

and the output is this

**output**
`1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10`

Comment: What output you getting ? What is your expected result ?

Comment: my expected result is this
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10

using for loop
how to do this?

Comment: And what you getting ? Loop over what ?

Comment: Post the code of your `number_ series_ class` class and the `print_number()` method.

Comment: sorry for the question.

but this is only a exercise
the question is this

$myobj = new number_ series_ class(10);
$myobj->print_number();

and the expected output is this

1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
how to output using do while or for
sorry for not clear question

Comment: If this is an exercise, you ought to have at least tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but do you want this ?

```
class number_series_class{
  private $index; 
  function number_series_class($num){
    $this->index = $num;
  }
  function print_number(){
    for ($i=1; $i <=$this->index; $i++) { 
      if($i!=$this->index) echo $i.'-';
      else echo $i;
    }
  }
}

$myobj = new number_series_class(10);
$myobj->print_number();
```

Comment: yuh
thanks
this is the result
sorry for my bad question
im still noob
THANKS SIR @Adesh Pandey

Comment: nop buddy! enjoy your development journey :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class number_series_class
{
    public $num;

     function __construct($number)
     {
       $this->num = $number;
     }

     function print_number()
     {
        $arr_temp = array();
        for($i=1; $i<=$this->num; $i++)
        {
            $arr_temp[] = $i;
        }
        echo implode("-", $arr_temp);
     }
}

$myobj = new number_series_class(10);
$myobj->print_number(); // output :  1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10

$myobj2 = new number_series_class(5);
$myobj2->print_number(); // output :  1-2-3-4-5
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer and this is right.
sorry for my noob question still learning php oop

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class number_series_class {

public $var ;

function __construct($var) {

$this->var = $var ;

}

function print_number() {

    $j = '';
    for($i=1; $i<=$this->var; $i++) {
        if($i == 10) {
        $j .= $i;
        }
        else {
        $j .= $i."-";
        }
    }

    return $j ;
}
}

$ob = new number_series_class(10);
echo $ob->print_number();
?>
```

Comment: thanks sir Rizwan Shamsher Kaim.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't especially clear, but I think you might want to look at the Iterator interfaces in the PHP SPL:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php

There are lots to choose from which offer slightly differing kinds of functionality.  The most straightforward is just called Iterator, and that lets you use `foreach` on your object.

I'm going to tweak your example a bit and say you have a class called NumberSeries, like this:

```
class NumberSeries implements Iterator
{
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array();

    public function __construct($max)
    {
        if ( !is_integer($max) || $max < 1 ) {
            throw new Exception('You must supply a positive integer!');
        }
        $this->array = range(1, $max);
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }

    function getNumberString() {
        return implode('-', $this->array);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$number_series = new NumberSeries(10);
foreach ( $number_series as $number ) {
    print $number;
}
print $number_series->getNumberString();
```

Probably *even better* than insisting on being Object Oriented is using a generator.  In fact, the PHP documentation on generators does something that will give you exactly the output you want:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

As you can hopefully see there, you could implement the "xrange" generator like this:

```
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$number_range = xrange(1, 10);
foreach ( $number_range as $number ) {
    print $number;
}
```

Note though that the exact output you've asked for is a bit trickier to do like this since generator objects (what you get back from xrange) aren't arrays, and you can't just call "implode('-', $array)" on them.